# scanf seg faults and it shouldn't

Tags: c

I really cannot find error in this function, please help! It seg faults in `scanf`. It should insert an element in queue implemented as circle buffer:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int n, front, rear;
int A[100];

#define True 1
#define False 0
#define UNDERFLOW -1589

int insert(void);
int delete(void);

int main(void)
{
    int option;

    //Unos i error checking
    printf("Unesite kapacitet bafera:");

    while(True)
    {
        if (scanf("%d", &n) != 0)
        {
            if (n > 0 && n < 100)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Kapacitet je ceo broj izmedju 0 i 100, pokusajmo ponovo");
                continue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Kapacitet je ceo broj izmedju 0 i 100");
            return 1;
        }
    }


    front = n;
    rear = n;

    while(True)
    {
        printf("\n\n IZABERITE OPCIJU \\n\n");
        printf("1 DODAJ ELEMENT\n");
        printf("2 UKLONI ELEMENT\n");
        printf("3 OCITAJ ELEMENT NA POCETKU REDA\n");
        printf("4 PRIKAZI BROJ ZAUZETIH MESTA\n");
        printf("5 PRIKAZI MAKSIMALNI KAPACITET REDA\n");
        printf("6 IZLAZ\n");

        scanf("%d", option);

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: insert(); break;
            case 2: delete(); break;
//          case 3: pop(); break;
//          case 4: space_left(); break;
//          case 5: capacity(); break;
//          case 6: return 0; break;
            default: printf("Pogresan unos!"); break;
        }

    }

}

/**
 * Ubacivanje u red.
 * Vrednosti koje funkcija vraca:
 * 0-element je uspesno ubacen
 * 1-overflow
 * 2-pogresan unos
 */
int insert(void)
{
    int h;
    printf("Unesite broj koji treba dodati:");

    scanf("%d", &h);

//      if (scanf("%d", &h) != 0)
//      {
//          printf("Morate uneti ceo broj!");
//          return 2;
//      }
    rear = rear % n + 1;
    if (front == rear)
    {
        return 1; //overflow
    }
    else
    {
        A[rear] = h;
        return 0;
    }
}

/**
 * Brise element iz reda i vraca njegovu vrecdnost.
 * Ako vrati UNDERFLOW, znaci da je overflow
 */
int delete(void)
{
    int x;

    if (front == rear)
    {
        return UNDERFLOW;
    }
    else
    {
        x = A[front];
        front = front % n + 1;
        return x;
    }
}
```

I get this message:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a6d0d5 in _IO_vfscanf_internal (s=<optimized out>, format=<optimized out>, argptr=argptr@entry=0x7fffffffdc88, errp=errp@entry=0x0) at vfscanf.c:1826
1826    vfscanf.c: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: Are you sure the `scanf()` fails? Did you use a debugger to confirm that?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). `rear`, `n`, `front` and `A` are undefined here.

Comment: when asking about a run time error, always include code that cleanly compiles,  Amongst other things, post the #include statements.

Comment: please indent consistently.  The page where code can be entered has the `{}` button that will do that for you.

Comment: I think scanf fails, yeah...

Comment: the posted code fails to show the declaration for A[],   The posted code fails to show the declaration for `n` nor indicate its' current value.  The posted code fails to show the declaration for `front` nor its' current value.  The posted code fails to show the declaration for `rear` nor its' current value.

Comment: @user3629249 the posted code shows all of above. They're global variables.

Comment: `scanf("%d", option);` should be `scanf("%d", &option);`

Comment: this line: `rear = rear % n + 1;` is probably wrong as the `+` operator has a higher precedence than `%`,  so the 0 offset in array `A[]` will never be set.   In C, array offsets start with 0 and continue to 'number of elements in array -1  so the line will never hit the first element in `A[]` and can access beyond the upper bound of the array.  Accessing beyond the upper bound of an array is undefined behaviour and can lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: in C, rather than #define'ing values for true and false, much better to use: `#include <stdbool.h>`

Comment: Yeah, it was option, it works now, thank you!

Comment: these kind of lines: `front = front % n + 1;` should be: `front++; front %= n;`  Similar consideration needs to be given when incrementing the `rear` variable.

Comment: It would have been nice if the question had mentioned that the code is trying insert/delete elements in a circular buffer.

Comment: The posted code, when I first copied it, only showed the `insert()` function.  That is the root cause of my early comments

Answer (score 2):

You should change:
`scanf("%d", option);` to `scanf("%d", &option);`

You used unitialized `int` as a pointer, and it could point anywhere, that's why you got segmentation fault

Answer (score 0):

In ***line 56*** you should change the statement

`scanf("%d", option);` to
`scanf("%d", &option);`

When I ran your code, I got the following warning:

`stackOv.c: In function ‘main’:
stackOv.c:56:9: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int’ [-Wformat=]
         scanf("%d", option);`

I immediately went to this line and I fixed it, it started running perfectly :). I hope this solves the problem.